# How to select multiple columns with pluck() from selection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The probleme is that when dd($responsablle or $type) its shows only first_name
i need to select first_name and id

```
public function create(){
        $responsable = User::all()->pluck('first_name','id');
        $type = EventType::all()->pluck('type','id');
        return view ('backend.event.create', compact('responsable', 'type'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `pluck` on the Builder instead of retrieving all the records with all their fields then `pluck`ing the fields from the Collection:

```
$responsable = User::pluck('first_name', 'id');
$type = EventType::pluck('type', 'id');
```

The second arguement is the field you want to key the Collection/array by.  The `id` part is the **key** of the element:

```
foreach ($responsable as $key => $value) {
    // $key is the 'id' field
    // $value is the 'first_name'
}

foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
    // $key is the 'id' field
    // $value is the 'type'
}
```

Or to be more useful with the naming:

```
foreach ($responsable as $id => $first_name) { ... }
foreach ($type as $id => $type) { ... }
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) `pluck`

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) `pluck`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you don't actually have to use `pluck()` here. If you simply limit the columns being returned via `->select()`, you will receive records with their attributes limited to the columns specified:

```
$users = User::select('first_name', 'id')->get();
$types = EventType::select('type', 'id')->get();
```

Now, when looping over these, you'll have access to `first_name`, `id` and `type`, `id`:

```
foreach($users AS $user){
  echo $user->id."|".$user->first_name;
}

foreach($types AS $type){
  echo $type->type."|".$type->id;
}
```

Note, this does return the full Model for `User` and `EventType`, but casting to an `array` will condense that to just an associative array for each record:

```
$users = User::select('first_name', 'id')->get()->toArray();
dd($users);

/* array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "first_name" => "Bob"
    "id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "first_name" => "Mike"
    "id" => "2"
  ]
] */

$types = EventType::select('type', 'id')->get()->toArray();
dd($types);

/* array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "Red"
    "id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "type" => "Blue"
    "id" => "2"
  ]
] */
```

Then, when looping, you can access similarly:

```
foreach($users AS $user){
  echo $user["id"]."|".$user["first_name"];
}

// Or, $users[0]["first_name"], etc.

foreach($types AS $type){
  echo $type["type"]."|".$type["id"];
}

// Or, $types[0]["type"], etc.
```

Comment: the problem is that i can't acces the id from $type with this $type->id i get an error :  Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: That means you're not looping. Notice how I say "Now, when looping over these [...]". `$types` is a `Collection`, when you loop `foreach($types AS $type)`, then `$type` is an instance of `EventType`, and you can access `$type->id`.